# c sizeof integer alignment?

Tags: c, sizeof

Hi I understand that C standard requires memory alignment when doing sizeof. But I don't quite understand why even integer arrays need to be aligned. See my following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct flexarray {
    int a[2];
    double f;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("sizeof (struct flexarray) = %zu\n", sizeof (struct flexarray));
    return 0;
}
```

output is 16 because `sizeof(int)` = 4 and `sizeof(double)` = 8. That is fine.

But when I change a to be `int[3]` then output is 24 That is not what I am expected because according to my calculation result should be 20 (= 3 x 4 + 8).

The only explanation I could think of is that compiler adds a padding integer but I don't understand why this happens: `sizeof(int[3])` is 12 and it is a multiple of 4 bytes after all.

I am compiling on a 32-bit Linux with gcc.

```
Linux 93c9e1096795 3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Feb 16 17:03:50 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Can anybody tell me why please?

Comment: "Hi I understand that C standard requires memory alignment when doing `sizeof`" - Ehm, no! What has `sizeof` to do with alignment? They are unrelated in the first place.

Comment: Alignment is related to memory access. It's not related to `sizeof` or C standard at all, except affecting structure sizes and making the struct size different

Comment: It sounds like doubles need to be aligned on 8-byte boundaries on your platform.  So 4 bytes of padding need to be inserted after your `int [3]` array to achieve that.  Seems clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `offsetof` to check the position of the class's members, you will likely to find that the compiler wants `double` values to be aligned on 8-byte boundaries.

Comment: C does not support classes. And to check the alignment, use `_Alignof`/`alignof`, not `offsetof`.